# Компилятор не находит метод

Tags: c#, xaml

Существует тег `xaml`:

```
<Button Content="Изменить" Click="Button_Click" Height="23"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Margin="12,105,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
```

и в отдельном файле `.cs` определен метод `Button_Click`:

```
using System;

namespace HouseholdServiceReport
{
    public class AnotherClass
    {
        public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyClass myclass = (MyClass)this.Resources["HouseholdServiceReport"];
            myclass.Service = "Парикмахерские"; // Меняем с "Рестораны" на "Парикмахерские"
        }
    }
}
```

Однако компилятор выводит ошибку:

> "HouseholdServiceReport.MainWindow" не содержит определение для "Button_Click". Не удалось найти метод  расширения "Button_Click", принимающий первый аргумент типа "HouseholdServiceReport.MainWindow"  (пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку?)"

Никак не пойму, что же я упустил.

Comment: ну так содержит ли класс `HouseholdServiceReport.MainWindow` метод `Button_Click`? То, что вы такой метод определили в каком то другом классе ничего не значит. Вам конкретно написали в каком классе не хватает какого метода

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите из XAML ссылку на событие `Click`, дайте имя кнопке `_buttonOK`. напишите следующее

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AnotherClass anotherClass = new AnotherClass();
        this._buttonOK.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(anotherClass.Button_Click);
    }
}
```